# Orchard - How to understand if I'm calling from Admin panel

Tags: orchardcms, action-filter

I need to execute some code everytime I load a page, except if the page belongs to the admin panel. I created an IActionFilter and in the OnActionExecuting method I tried to check for the Controller name, but it isn't an optimal solution because there are a lot of different controllers being called from the dashboard. Is there a more efficient way to recognize if I'm loading a page of the admin panel?

Comment: I just discovered something similar to what you're describing today in [this module](https://bitbucket.org/bleroy/nwazet.tree/src/d9d7d9288aa4d2e6314be1ecca08db9ffdb909fb/Filters/AdminFilter.cs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). Maybe that works for you?

It's line 24 to be specific

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is

```
using Orchard.UI.Admin;
```

&

```
if (AdminFilter.IsApplied(filterContext.RequestContext))
{
    // This is an admin page, do nothing
    return;
}
```